# htaccess - How to allow negative numbers in mod-rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In htaccess file I have that line:

```
RewriteRule ^something,([0-9]+)\.html$ something.php?num=$1 [L]
```

And if I open page with any number like `something,7.html` then everything works perfect, but how can I change rewrite rule if I want use a negative numbers as well, for example `something,-2.html`. Also I don't want to allow use letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your regular expression to check for an optional "minus":

```
^something,(-?[0-9]+)\.html$
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a `\-?` inside your match selection:

```
RewriteRule ^something,(\-?[0-9]+)\.html$ something.php?num=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the dash?